# How do I conditionally redirect referrers to different webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a JavaScript "Count down then redirect" script for my website. I want to use something like http referer in the script attached below:

```
<script>
<!--

/*
Count down then redirect script
By JavaScript Kit (http://javascriptkit.com)
*/

//change below target URL to your own
var targetURL="www.domain.com";

//change the second to start counting down from
var countdownfrom=20;

var currentsecond = document.redirect.redirect2.value =
    countdownfrom + 1;

function countredirect() {
  if (currentsecond != 1) {
    currentsecond -= 1;
    document.redirect.redirect2.value = currentsecond
  } else {
    window.location = targetURL;
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(countredirect, 1000);
}

countredirect();
//-->
</script>
```

I want the script to work like:

If some one arrive from www.twitter.com, they will be redirected to www.domain.com/twitter.html after the count down.

If some one arrive from www.facebook.com, they will be redirected to www.domain.com/facebook.html after the count down.

If some one arrive from www.youtube.com, they will be redirected to www.domain.com/youtube.html after the count down.

I want to redirect 15-20 URL. Please help !! How can I do it ??

Comment: I've deleted your [tag:java] tag as your question appears to have nothing to do with use of this language.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
var targetURL = /www\.xxx\.com/i.test(document.referrer) ?
    "www.domain-for-xxx.com" : "www.domain-for-yyy.com";
```

Multiple Referrers:

```
var targetUrl = "http://defaulturl.com/";
if (/www\.xxx\.com/i.test(document.referrer)) {
  targetUrl = "http://www.domain-for-xxx.com/";
} else if (/www\.yyy\.com/i.test(document.referrer)) {
  targetUrl = "http://www.domain-for-yyy.com/";
}
...
```

Comment: I need to add multiple referer and define their redirect URL... How do I do it ?

Comment: Just use an `if (xxx) { targetUrl = 'xxx' } else if (yyy) { targetUrl = 'yyy' }` block. You can have as many `else if` statements as you wish.

Comment: How do I define multiple referer here ? If I use 4/5 referer than what should i put here ?

    var targetURL = /www\.xxx\.com/i.test(document.referrer) ?
    "www.domain-for-xxx.com" : "www.domain-for-yyy.com";

Comment: I am still confused and unable to get it... Let me clarify what I want in that javascript:

I want to redirect referrers into different webpages. For example:

If some one arrive from www.facebook.com, they will be redirected to www.domain.com/facebook.html

If some one arrive from www.twitter.com, they will be redirected to www.domain.com/twitter.html

Comment: I expanded the answer - but this is pretty basic JavaScript. If you need more help, you should ask a separate question.